# Does the Cornu Spiral change?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

The Cornu Spiral is used in calculations for Fresnel Diffraction. I have seen images of the Cornu Spiral and cannot find an answer to this question:

Is the Cornu Spiral a constant reference graph used to help evaluate diffraction intensities, or does the graph change depending on whether you are dealing with a single slit, circular aperture, opaque barrier, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve formed by adding infinitesimal amplitudes graphically (in the process of arriving at the resultant amplitude) is called a vibration curve, which is different for apertures of different shapes. The vibration curve for slit-like geometries is called a Cornu spiral.

Reading Secs 15.4, 18.6, and 18.9 (they are short) from Jenkins & White (Fundamental of Optics) will clear your doubt once and for all.